# c# winforms - inaccessible control on a child Form

Tags: c#, winforms

eternal question about twoForms:

```
frm02 frm02 = new frm02();
frm02.Text = "Objects";
ds02 = new DataSet();
ds02.ReadXml(path02);
frm02.dgv02.DataSource = ds02.Tables[0];  //error: dgv02 is inaccessible...
frm02.ShowDialog();
```

pleaseHelp!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make `dgv02` *public*.  By default, when you add types via the designer, they are not public.  You can edit their properties in the design window, and change the accessibility level to public.

That being said, a better option might be to create a public property that returns the appropriate control, or, even better, allows you to set the data.  For example, if you add this method to your form:

```
public void SetDatasource(DataSet data)
{
     this.dgv02.DataSource = data;
}
```

You could then call this as:

```
frm02.SetDatasource(ds02);
```

Comment: but dgv02 has not allways ds02 as DataSource. Next time it will be ds03 or whatever ?

Comment: @Bonaca This lets you set it from anywhere - I only used ds02 since that's what your code used...

Comment: Ok, itWorks. But why is it so complicated. Why not only: frm02.dgv02.DataSource = ds02. Why all about the protections. Protections from Wind, Snow, Sun... from What ?

Comment: @Bonaca By default, things are private in your class.  This means you can only change them from within the class, which provides "protection", meaning that later, if you change the internal implementation of your class, the code which uses the class won't break and need changing.  You typically make the public API of your class in a way so you can change how the class works internally without breaking users of your class/form/etc.

Comment: thanks, Copsey. I will start writing a new Language, this days. Something like vba. For private and Public :). ThanksAgain.